# Merge rows and keep values based on another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got data from a number of surveys. Each survey can be sent multiple times with updated values. For each survey/row in the dataset there's a date when the survey was submited (created). I'd like to merge the rows for each survey and keep the date from the first survey but other data from the last survey.

A simple example:

```r
#>   survey    created var1 var2
#> 1     s1 2020-01-01   10   30
#> 2     s2 2020-01-02   10   90
#> 3     s2 2020-01-03   20   20
#> 4     s3 2020-01-01   45    5
#> 5     s3 2020-01-02   50   50
#> 6     s3 2020-01-03   30   10
```

Desired result:

```r
#>   survey    created var1 var2
#> 1     s1 2020-01-01   10   30
#> 2     s2 2020-01-02   20   20
#> 3     s3 2020-01-01   30   10
```

Example data:

```r
df <- data.frame(survey = c("s1", "s2", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s3"),
                created = as.POSIXct(c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03"), "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "GMT"),
                var1 = c(10, 10, 20, 45, 50, 30),
                var2 = c(30, 90, 20, 5, 50, 10),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I've tried `group_by` with `summarize` in different ways but can't make it work, any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After grouping by 'survey', change the 'created' as the `first` or `min` value in 'created' and then `slice` the last row (`n()`)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(survey) %>% 
   mutate(created = as.Date(first(created))) %>% 
   slice(n())
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   survey [3]
#  survey created     var1  var2
#  <chr>  <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
#1 s1     2020-01-01    10    30
#2 s2     2020-01-02    20    20
#3 s3     2020-01-01    30    10
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
transform(df, created = ave(created, survey, FUN = first)
         )[!duplicated(df$survey, fromLast = TRUE),]
```

Answer (score 2):

After selecting the first `created` date we can select the `last` values from all the columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(survey) %>%
  mutate(created = as.Date(first(created))) %>%
  summarise(across(created:var2, last))
  #In older version use `summarise_at`
  #summarise_at(vars(created:var2), last)


# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  survey created     var1  var2
#  <chr>  <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
#1 s1     2020-01-01    10    30
#2 s2     2020-01-02    20    20
#3 s3     2020-01-01    30    10
```